# How to create different instance for SDWebImageManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I have many controllers where I download images using SDWebImage Library. I am using following code

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlToDownloadFrom] options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL)
     {
         _productInfo.isDownloading = false;

         _productInfo.isImageDownloadedScuessfully = finished;

        if (image)
        {
            [_productInfo setMainImg:image];
            canShowListView ? [self.listCollectionView reloadData] : [self.gridCollectionView reloadData];
        }
    }];
```

As seen in code I am using SDWebImageManager shared instance to download the data, because of these all my downloading operation go inside a queue in FIFO series. So for example I have a controller where I am downloading 10 images, then I push another controller above it which downloads more 5 images. So for these new images which are from top controller they have to wait till previous controller download those 10 images. How can I solve this problem? Only possible solution I can think is creating new instance of SDWebImageManager, but that also create SDWebImageDownloader shared instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SDWebImageDownloader`? I remember it had a queue of download operations and you can configure the number of concurrent downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibililty as I see is, when you call:

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:
```

which is defined in [this class (SDWebImageDownloader)](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDownloader.m), implements an NSOperationQueue for maintaining queued operation and the priority of this queue can be set [see the Priority section in here](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/).

My advice is that, perhaps setting the priority of this queue can fix your problem.